# Why is it taking forever to install RSAT

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I'm developing in a windows 10 environment.

I need Active Directory Module for Powershell.

A pre-requisite is to install RSAT.

I used the script provided here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Install-the-Active-fd32e541/view/Discussions#content

after more than 2 hours, this it's still installing:

[image: Taking forever to install RSAT]

Anyone have any pointers?  Thank you!

Comment: RSAT tools are a feature... `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName rsatclient`

Comment: Thanks @TheIncorrible1, although I deeply hope that handle doesn't describe the real you!

Comment: Just a nickname from a friend that stuck.  It'd be hard for it to describe me and to still excel in the tech industry.